# Error: Unauthorized on my own Google Cloud notebook

Tags: google-compute-engine, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter-notebook

I just built a Compute Engine app with a Ubuntu 16.04 VM, launched it in Chrome, installed python3, the ipython kernel, and some libraries, so that I could run  Jupyter notebooks. Here are the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-dev libzmq-dev
sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo pip3 install ipython pyzmq jinja2 tornado jsonschema
sudo pip3 install jupyter
sudo ipython kernel install
sudo pip3 install numpy scipy scikit-learn pandas matplotlib
```

The last command gave this message, twice:

> The directory '/home/allennugent/.cache/pip' or its parent directory
>   is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled.
>   check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip
>   with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Hoping this wouldn't be a show-stopper, I went on to set up a firewall rule with Source IP ranges = '0.0.0.0/0' and Protocols and ports = 'tcp:8888'. Then I launched jupyter:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser &
```

This created hyperlink to the notebook. When I click on the link (in the Serial Console window), a browser page opens with

> Error: Unauthorized  You are currently logged in as [my gmail address]
>   which does not have access to Cloud Shell 3118611.

According to the Cloud Platform dashboard I *was* logged in under the same account name when I set up the Compute Engine, so I don't know what is going wrong with the authorization.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too and for me it was solved by typing the VM's external IP and port in the address bar without http or https:// preceding it.

e.g. `xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888`

Then for my notebook I was required to copy the access token (the token=[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] part, just the characters in square brackets here) from the terminal into the password prompt when jupyter shows in the browser.

Comment: get this erros: host at <IP> refused to connect. Any idea how to enable external access on Gcloud? Their documentation is a mess.